# One of my Tkinter checkbuttons is not updating its value within a nested function when I call it

Tags: python, tkinter, checkbox

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("SW Damage Calculator")

frame1 = LabelFrame(root, text="Single Stat Scaling", padx=10, pady=10)
frame1.grid(row=1, column=0)

def scaling1():
    def totalstat():
        def_break_toggle = getdouble(def_break_val.get())
        atk_buff_toggle = getdouble(atk_buff_val.get())

        tot_dmg.set((
                            ((b_stat + r_stat +
                              ((atower1_stat / 100) * b_stat) +
                              ((atower2_stat / 100) * b_stat) +
                              ((leadskill_stat / 100) * b_stat)) * atk_buff_toggle) *
                            (1 + ((atowercd_stat + cd_stat) / 100))) *
                    ((skill_multiplier + skill_ups) / 100) *
                    (1000 / (1140 + 3.5 * (en_def_stat * def_break_toggle)))

    defbreak = Label(frame1, text="Defence Break")
    def_break_val = DoubleVar(frame1)
    def_break = Checkbutton(frame1, offvalue=1, onvalue=0.3, variable=def_break_val, textvariable=def_break_val)
    def_break_val.set(1)

    atkbuff = Label(frame1, text="Attack Buff")
    atk_buff_val = DoubleVar(frame1)
    atk_buff = Checkbutton(frame1, offvalue=1, onvalue=1.5, variable=atk_buff_val, textvariable=atk_buff_val)
    atk_buff_val.set(1)

    tot_dmg = DoubleVar()
    tot_damage = Label(frame1, textvariable=tot_dmg)

    add_stats = Button(frame1, text="Total Stat", command=totalstat)

    tot_damage.grid(row=8, column=1)
    add_stats.grid(row=9, column=1)

    defbreak.grid(row=5, column=2)
    def_break.grid(row=5, column=3)

    atkbuff.grid(row=4, column=2)
    atk_buff.grid(row=4, column=3)

ScalingButton1 = Button(frame1, text="Single Stat Scaling", command=scaling1)
ScalingButton1.grid(row=0, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

I'm creating a damage calculator for a game I play. All of the code works except that the checkbutton variable "atk_buff_val" does not update within the "totalstat" function. The off value is initialized but it never changes to 1.5 in "totalstat" when I check it. However my other checkbutton "def_break_val" works perfectly fine even though the code is pretty much the same for the both of them so I'm confused as to what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: There's quite a bit of code included here which doesn't directly relate to your specific question. Could you condense this to a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Also, you might want to try a `DoubleVar` in place of an `IntVar`, as the values you're working with are not whole numbers. https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm

Comment: Condensed code, and changed from IntVar to DoubleVar and it worked! Thank you so much @BenDelaney.